# Is there a way I can remove a character from a string?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to remove a character ('#') from a `string`,

I tried to check if the `string` has '#' with the `find` function, which it does, then erase this with the `erase` function.

For some reason I get a run time error that says I have no memory.

Error: `std::out_of_range at memory location 0x003BF3B4`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello World#";

    if (str.find('#')) {
        str.erase('#');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*The excepted output is: "Hello World"*

Comment: `str.erase` takes an iterator, not a character. Try `str.erase(str.find('#'));`

Comment: Post the actual error too, not what you think it means. I bet the actual error complains about accessing invalid memory, not that there's no RAM. For security reasons, modern compilers try to detect invalid memory access in various ways, so when you try to read from an invalid address or a location 50 bytes after an array's end, they'll complain

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will edit my question.

Comment: The error says `out of range`, not out of memory. It means you tried to access a location outside the string. Wander3r explained what's wrong - `erase` expects an iterator, essentially the *result* of `str.find`, and tried to use `'#'` as if it were a location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Hello World#";
    char c = '#';

    /* Removing character c from s */
    s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), c), s.end());
    std::cout << "\nString after removing the character "
              << c << " : " << s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '#'), str.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all '#' from the string:

```
std::string str = "Hello World#";
std::size_t pos = str.find('#');
while(pos != std::string::npos)
{
    str.erase(pos, 1); //<- edited here
    pos = str.find('#');
}

cout << str;
```

Comment: In this answer, when I add '#' at the beginning of the string, it just delete the whole string and the output is empty.